# two-dimensional array with many values

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to convert the data from this table in to a two-dimensional array.
[image: desc]

This is the code I have so far

```
int[,] distanceArray = new int[10, 10];
        int[] chicago = new int[] { 1004, 921, 1230, 272, 2716, 860, 1307, 2820, 2887 };
        int[] dallas = new int[] { 1753, 1780, 1899, 2570, 1858, 1494, 2734, 571 };
        int[] lasVegas = new int[] { 2752, 2048, 1343, 1732, 2523, 3447, 1099 };
        int[] losAngeles = new int[] { 3017, 1397, 517, 2251, 1278, 1057 };
        int[] miami = new int[] { 1520, 919, 1435, 1322, 2646 };
        int[] newOrleans = new int[] { 1507, 515, 2234, 2420 };
        int[] toronto = new int[] { 609, 2176, 1307 };
        int[] vancouver = new int[] { 3155, 709 };
        int washingtonDC = 448;

        int counter = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < counter; y++)
            {
                if (counter == 9)
                {
                    distanceArray[(y + 1), y] = chicago[y];
                    distanceArray[y, (y + 1)] = chicago[y];
                }
                if (counter == 8)
                {
                    distanceArray[(y + 2), y] = dallas[y];
                    distanceArray[y, (y + 2)] = dallas[y];
                }
                if (counter == 7)
                {
                    distanceArray[(y + 3), y] = lasVegas[y];
                    distanceArray[y, (y + 3)] = lasVegas[y];
                }
                if (counter == 6)
                {
                    distanceArray[(y + 4), y] = losAngeles[y];
                    distanceArray[y, (y + 4)] = losAngeles[y];
                }
                if (counter == 5)
                {
                    distanceArray[(y + 5), y] = miami[y];
                    distanceArray[y, (y + 5)] = miami[y];
                }
                if (counter == 4)
                {
                    distanceArray[(y + 6), y] = newOrleans[y];
                    distanceArray[y, (y + 6)] = newOrleans[y];
                }
                if (counter == 3)
                {
                    distanceArray[(y + 7), y] = toronto[y];
                    distanceArray[y, (y + 7)] = toronto[y];
                }
                if (counter == 2)
                {
                    distanceArray[(y + 8), y] = vancouver[y];
                    distanceArray[y, (y + 8)] = vancouver[y];
                }
                if (counter == 1)
                {
                    distanceArray[(y + 9), y] = washingtonDC;
                    distanceArray[y, (y + 9)] = washingtonDC;
                }

            }

            counter--;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                Console.Write(distanceArray[i, y] + "\t");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

But I'm getting this output
[image: out]

For some reason the final values are not being applied. What am I doing wrong? Is there a more efficient way to achieve this goal?

Comment: why you fill your arrays (for example this one `int[] chicago = new int[] { 1004, 921, 1230, 272, 2716, 860, 1307, 2820, 2887 };`) like that?

Comment: Your initialization seems to have nothing to do with the printed table you show. Not only have you not included the 0-length distance-to-self value that shows up in the diagonal on the printed table, even the other numbers are in large part completely different, showing distances from apparently entirely different city pairs than the one being initialized. It seems to me that if you'd just create a 2-d array that looks exactly like the table, you'd be fine.

Comment: Sounds like you have turned this into an XY problem. May I ask what are you _actually_ trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete example that generate the table given.
Problem is that the values of array mention in your code is less than the values mention in table.

```
  class Program
{
    public static int w = 0;
    public static int y = 1;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[,] twodimention = new int[10, 10];
        int[] boston = new int[] { 0, 1004, 1753, 2752,3017 ,1520 , 1507, 609, 3155,448 };
        int[] chicago = new int[] { 1004, 0, 921, 1780, 2048, 1397, 919, 515, 2176,709 };
        int[] dallas = new int[] { 1753, 921, 0, 1230, 1399, 1343, 517, 1435,2234,1307 };
        int[] lasVegas = new int[] { 2752, 1708, 1230, 0, 272, 2570, 1732,2251,1322,2420 };
        int[] losAngeles = new int[] { 3017, 2048, 1399, 272,0, 2716,1858,2523,1278,2646 };
        int[] miami = new int[] { 1520, 1397, 1343, 2570, 2716,0,860,1494,3447,1057 };
        int[] newOrleans = new int[] { 1507, 919, 517, 1732,1858,860,0,1307,2734,1099 };
        int[] toronto = new int[] { 609, 515, 1435,2251,2523,1494,1307,0,2820,571 };
        int[] vancouver = new int[] { 3155,2176,2234,1322,1278,3447,2734,2820,0,2887 };
        int[] washington = new int[] { 448, 709, 1307, 2420, 2646, 1057, 1099, 571, 2887,0 };
        int x = 9;

        for (int row = 0; row <= x; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col <=9; col++)
            {
                if (w == 0)
                {
                    if (col ==boston.Length - 1 || col < boston.Length - 1)
                    {
                        twodimention[row, col] = boston[col];

                    }
                }
                if (w==1)
                {
                    if(col==chicago.Length-1 || col<chicago.Length - 1)
                    {
                        twodimention[row, col] = chicago[col];

                    }
                }
                if (w == 2)
                {
                    if (col == dallas.Length - 1 || col < dallas.Length - 1)
                    {


                        twodimention[row, col] = dallas[col];
                    }
                }
                if (w == 3)
                {
                    if (col == lasVegas.Length - 1 || col < lasVegas.Length - 1)
                    {

                        twodimention[row, col] = lasVegas[col];
                    }
                }
                if (w == 4)
                {
                    if (col == losAngeles.Length - 1 || col < losAngeles.Length - 1)
                    {
                        twodimention[row, col] = losAngeles[col];
                    }
                }
                if (w == 5)
                {
                    if (col == miami.Length - 1 || col < miami.Length - 1)
                    {
                        twodimention[row, col] = miami[col];
                    }

                }
                if (w == 6)
                {
                    if (col == newOrleans.Length - 1 || col < newOrleans.Length - 1)
                    {
                        twodimention[row, col] = newOrleans[col];
                    }
                }
                if (w == 7)
                {
                    if (col == toronto.Length - 1 || col < toronto.Length - 1)
                    {
                        twodimention[row, col] = toronto[col];
                    }
                }
                if (w == 8)
                {
                    if (col == vancouver.Length - 1 || col < vancouver.Length - 1)
                    {
                        twodimention[row, col] = vancouver[col];
                    }
                }
                if (w == 9)
                {
                    if (col == washington.Length - 1 || col < washington.Length - 1)
                    {
                        twodimention[row, col] = washington[col];
                    }
                }

            }


            w = w + 1;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int row = 0; row <= x; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col <= 9; col++)
            {
           Console.Write(twodimention[row, col]+"\t");

            }



        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an initializer for every value in the grid. Yes, there is symmetry in the grid of distances, but you asked for an efficient method!

```
int[,] distanceArray = new int[10, 10]
{
  {0, 1004, 1753, 2752, 3017, 1520, 1507, 609, 3155, 448}, // Boston
  {1004, 0, 921, 1780, ... etc},                           // Chicago
   ...
  {448, 709,1307,2420,2646,1057,1099,571,2887,0}           // Washington DC
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me why you are initializing the array the way you are. The values in each city's array do not appear to relate to the values you show in the table. For example, the third value in the `chicago` array appears to be the distance between Dallas and Las Vegas (i.e. *not* between Chicago and some other city). It's also not clear to me why if you want a separate `distance` array, you don't just hard-code the values for *that*. Nor is it clear to me why you have the `counter` variable in your nested loops.

In other words, there's very little about the code you posted that makes sense to me. However, the basic goal seems clear enough. Here's how I'd do it (showing just four cities for the example…I assume you can take the basic example and extend it to all the cities you have):

```
enum City
{
    Boston,
    Chicago,
    Dallas,
    LasVegas,
}

static class CityDistance
{
    private static int[][] _distances =
    {
        new [] { 1004, 1753, 2752 },
        new [] { 921, 1780 },
        new [] { 1230 },
    };

    public static int GetDistance(City city1, City city2)
    {
        if (city1 == city2)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (city1 > city2)
        {
            City cityT = city1;
            city1 = city2;
            city2 = cityT;
        }

        int cityIndex1 = (int)city1, cityIndex2 = (int)city2 - (cityIndex1 + 1);

        return _distances[cityIndex1][cityIndex2];
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (City city1 in Enum.GetValues(typeof(City)))
        {
            foreach (City city2 in Enum.GetValues(typeof(City)))
            {
                Console.Write("{0,4}   ", CityDistance.GetDistance(city1, city2));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I introduce the use of an `enum` type to represent the actual cities. This is much better than relying on hard-coded integer values.
- I have abstracted the logic into a `CityDistances` class, where the data can be encapsulated, and a method that can map the basic query of "what's the distance between a pair of cities" into the logic required to access the stored data, without requiring the caller to care about how that data is stored.

With this approach, you can try different data representations, and the code that calls the `GetDistance()` method doesn't have to change. In this case, I've stored the data somewhat similarly to how it *seems* you are trying to do in your example, i.e. without duplicating data. This means the `GetDistance()` method needs to handle the 0-length scenario as a special case, and needs to normalize the input city values, so that the symmetrical nature of the data can be used.

Comment: Peter I think the values assign to the array in table mention above is more than the values initialize in code thats why he is not getting the same result .